# Spring cloud kafka stream Retry with cercit breaker

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, dlq

I have a 3 partition kafka topic to handle events and push the messages to exexternal service.

This is done by spring cloud kafka binding with functional approach in a kubernetes cluster.

In happy case working as expected.

When external service down ,we added a 3 times retry mechanisms introducing a retry topic .

Problem aarise if till the retry completed and still external service available.

What should be the approach need to follow.

**Solution 1**.Push it to database from dlq and procees through from a cron job manner.

**Solution 2** .If retry exusted and still external service down ,then pause the listener without acknowledge ing the message and resume once external service up (cercit breaker pattern),or application restart.

Sol 2 is work fine in case of 1 instance set up as it will resume the listener.

**Qs** : How to resume other listener running in other instance .(any listner rebalncing )

Is there any option read that particular offset and delete it on demand basis in spring cloud stream.

Or any better solution available ??